# Can I exclude some indices from searching in elasticsearch using java API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have around 50 indices in ES but I need to query 48 of them. Is there a way to exclude the 2 indices using the java API?

Comment: As far as I kno there is no such options to exclude just 2 indicies. I think you should be able to use aliases: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html